# How to pass a value (selected from selectOneMenu)from page JSF to another

Tags: jsf

I want to fill an selectOneMenu with fields from my DataBase
and then use the chosen value in another request SQL. 
For know I have my selectOneMenu  filled from my data but I dont Know how to retrieve the chosen value and show it into another page. The error is:
**org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /Result.jsp
Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:553)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:442)**

Also I want to write a clean code , I want to create class connection and use it to connect one time in the first page and deconnect at the last page(when I finish).

Bean:

```
public class BeanTools {

  private List<SelectItem> mesElements;
  private  String maValeur;
  public PreparedStatement st;
  Connectionx con = new Connectionx();  **//IF I do that on N page I will have N connection!!**
  Connection cx = (Connection) con.Connx();

      public BeanTools() {
    }     

    public String getMaValeur() {
        return maValeur;
    }

    public void setMaValeur(String maValeur) {
        this.maValeur = maValeur;
    }

    public void setMesElements(List<SelectItem> mesElements) {
        this.mesElements = mesElements;
    }




public Iterable<String> remplireItem() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {

String sql;
sql ="select issuestatus.pname from issuestatus;";
System.out.println("sql");
st=(PreparedStatement) cx.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery();System.out.println("execute");

String nbb;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while(rs1.next())
      {
          nbb = rs1.getString("pname");
          System.out.println(nbb);
          list.add(nbb);
          System.out.println("list"+list.toString());
      }


return list;
    }


public List<SelectItem> getMesElements() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

if (mesElements == null) {
mesElements = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
for (String val : remplireItem()) {
mesElements.add(new SelectItem(val));
}
}
return mesElements;
}
}
```

First JSF page:

```
<h:form id="form">       
 Issue status 2 :<h:selectOneMenu style="width:200px"  value="#{BeanTools.maValeur}" >
     <f:selectItems value="#{BeanTools.mesElements}"/>
                 </h:selectOneMenu>

 <h:commandButton action="submit" value="submit"/>
 </h:form>
```

Second JSF page:

```
<body>      
        <h:outputText  value="#{BeanTools.maValeur}" />

</body>
```

The Faces config:

```
<managed-bean>
<managed-bean-name>BeanTools</managed-bean-name>
<managed-bean-class>KPIs.BeanTools</managed-bean-class>
<managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

<navigation-rule>
<from-view-id>/welcomeJSF.jsp</from-view-id>
<navigation-case>
<from-outcome>submit</from-outcome>
<to-view-id>/Result.jsp</to-view-id> 
</navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Class Connection:

```
public class Connectionx {

public Connection cx=null;
public Statement st;

 public Connectionx() {}

public Connection Connx()
{

  System.out.println("enregister le driver");
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
                {
                System.err.println("Erreur lors du chargement du driver"+ex.getMessage() );


                }


        try {
            /** Connection  */
             cx =  (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection           ( "jdbc:mysql://localhost/jiradb","","" );

                }
                catch( SQLException ex )
                {
            System. err. println( "Error ")                }
  return cx;
}
```

The whole stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /Result.jsp at line 19

16:     <body>
17:         <h1>Hello World!</h1>
18:       
19:         <h:outputText   value="#{BeanTools.maValeur}" />
20:        
21:     </body>
22: </html>


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:553)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:442)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:154)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot@144c984 not expected type.  Expected: javax.faces.component.UIOutput.  Perhaps you're missing a tag?
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:907)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:840)
    at org.apache.jsp.Result_jsp._jspService(Result_jsp.java:84)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot@144c984 not expected type.  Expected: javax.faces.component.UIOutput.  Perhaps you're missing a tag?
    at com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.OutputTextTag.setProperties(OutputTextTag.java:126)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.findComponent(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:690)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.doStartTag(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1311)
    at com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.OutputTextTag.doStartTag(OutputTextTag.java:163)
    at org.apache.jsp.Result_jsp._jspx_meth_h_005foutputText_005f0(Result_jsp.java:103)
    at org.apache.jsp.Result_jsp._jspService(Result_jsp.java:73)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: Although the code does not expose the best practices, it should just work. What is the problem you're facing? What happens instead when you press the button? Or is your real question *actually* (in contrary to what you asked in the title) "Please review and rewrite this code for me"?

Comment: You've edited the question to add the exception message and the `Connection` class. But this is useless without the entire stacktrace. The stacktrace with the root cause(s) is the most important part of the exception. It namely contains the answer. Please also pay attention to the code formatting rules, your `Connection` class code is not properly formatted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, there's the root cause of the exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot@144c984 not expected type.  Expected: javax.faces.component.UIOutput.  Perhaps you're missing a tag?

You forgot the `<f:view>` in `Result.jsp`. All JSF components has to go inside a `<f:view>`. Edit your `Result.jsp` so that it look like the following basic template:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<f:view>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>JSP page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h:outputText value="JSF components here." />
        </body>
    </html>
</f:view>
```